# PInvoke in 64bit .net app through c++ 64 bit dll

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, pinvoke, dllexport

I'm having an issue calling a function in a c++ dll inside of a c# app. I'm calling the function inside of c# like so:

```
[DllImport("cryptopp.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr RSAEncryptString(string filename, string seed, string message);
```

It is being exported in the c++ dll as shown below.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* __cdecl RSAEncryptString(const char *pubFilename, const char *seed, const char *message);
```

What I get when I try to call this, however, is an "An External component has thrown an exception." exception, which is not very descriptive at all, and extremely unhelpful.

When I pull up the dll in an export viewer, it shows all the other exported functions with fully quantified declarations (I.E. public: void __cdecl CryptoPP::X509PublicKey::`vbase destructor'(void) __ptr64 ) , except for the function I am calling, which just displays the function name RSAEncryptString.

This is the only possible issue I can see, besides maybe mis-calling the function with an invalid declaration on the c# side. Am I using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal wrong?

Please help <3 and thanks in advance.

Comment: C functions that return a char* are extremely troublesome.  The classic mistake is returning a pointer to a local variable.  That has some odds of working when called from a C program, zero when being pinvoked.  Even if it is done right by the C code and it uses malloc() to allocate the string buffer, you still have an unsolvable memory leak.  You need the help of the code's author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change the first line to:

```
[DllImport("cryptopp.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

If you want to get very descriptive, you can also add these:

```
public static extern IntPtr RSAEncryptString(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string seed,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string message);
```

IIRC think the `CharSet` should take care of the encoding thing for you, but if it doesn't, use the `MarshalAs` also, as shown above.

---

Edit:

Oh I think I got why you still get an error! Your code still had the above problems, but it's still erring because you can't return a `string` object since it's not a managed object; you need to return a pointer (like `IntPtr`) and then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`!

(I didn't really look at your return type when answering this at first.)

Comment: Still getting the same exception...your suggestions make sense though, I'm honestly surprised that this didn't work heh

Comment: The string types are `const char *` types which are technically `LPCSTR`

Comment: @Aphex: Yeah, I'm aware of that, but that's what the `In` is for... there's no `UnmanagedType.LPCStr` member.

Comment: @sringer: In that case, it might be that your function is actually (really!!) corrupting memory!!! :)

Comment: :O this is no good...I just created a basic wrapper for the crypto++ libraries...it says something about it sharing a heap with the calling app, i guess i'll have to look more into that

Comment: @sringer: Have you tried changing the calling convention to `stdcall`? Maybe that'll catch something, just a thought...

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method, do you have a link to a tutorial/example?

Comment: All you need to do is change `CallingConvention.Cdecl` to `CallingConvention.StdCall` and `__cdecl` to `__stdcall`. :)

Comment: @Lambert I changed the function signature on the c++ side and returned an int* and returned as (int*)string.c_str(); but still the same exception. Am I doing it wrong? I'm new to this whole .net thing, so I apologize for my noobishness >.<

Comment: @sringer: No need to apologize for anything, you didn't do anything wrong! We're all here to learn. :) Now, regarding the cast: You don't need to cast anything else on the C++ side (`const char*` was fine), but you need to *receive* it as an `IntPtr` instead of a `string`... did you try that?

Comment: ah ok, yeah I was already doing that actually:  

IntPtr ptr = NativeMeth.RSAEncryptString(strKeyFile, ((int)span.TotalSeconds).ToString(), strMessage);  
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);  
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);   
return str;

Comment: Haha no problem, sorry it didn't get fixed.

Comment: slight breakthrough maybe? I made a separate console app to test through, and apparently the line Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr); is crashing the application, which might be what's throwing the external exception, (i forgot to mention that i'm actually implementing the native c++ methods inside of a c# class library, and the exception is getting caught in another app that is referencing the library). It successfully finds the function and has a valid return, and it exits the app with no break at Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr); Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: WHOA O__O everything just got ten times more complex. I'm guessing maybe you're not freeing the memory with the same allocator as what you used to allocate it, but without seeing your code, I have no idea.

Comment: problem fixed. handled the memory inside of the dll. no memory leaks and no exceptions :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to store the return value of type `const char *` (an `LPCSTR`) into an `IntPtr` type (usually used for `HANDLE`s, not `LPSTR`s.) Try this:

```
[DllImport("cryptopp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern String RSAEncryptString(String filename, String seed, String message);
```

Also keep in mind that if any argument is getting written to, you'll need to add `out` before its type, i.e. `..., out String message)`